# Pandas DF merge based on matching cell name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have a dataframe DF1 that contains:

| Asset Name | Type | Score | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | fruit | nan | nan |
| Pear | fruit | nan | nan |
| Banana | fruit | nan | nan |

I have DF2 that contains:

| Asset Name | Score | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | 40 | C |
| Banana | 100 | A |
| Pear | 60 | B |
| Potato | 10 | F |
| Apple | 70 | E |

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Asset Name':['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana'], \
         'Type':['fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit'],'Score':['nan', 'nan','nan'], \
             'Grade':['nan','nan','nan']}

data2 = {'Asset Name':['Orange', 'Banana','Pear','Potato','Apple'], \
         'Score':[40,100,60,10,70], 'Grade':['C','A','B','F','E']}
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I can use:

`combined = pd.concat([DF1, Df2]).groupby('Asset Name').first()`

This gives me the following:

| Asset Name | Score | Grade | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 70 | E | fruit |
| Banana | 100 | A | fruit |
| Orange | 40 | C | None |
| Pear | 60 | B | fruit |
| Potato | 10 | F | None |

This is not quite what I want. I only want the score and grade for Apple, Pear and Banana to be added, as they are in DF1. If the asset name is not in DF1 and Df2 then then Score and grade should not be updated.

Similarly if i try to use:

`combined = df2.combine_first(df1)`

| Asset Name | Grade | Score | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | C | 70 | fruit |
| Banana | A | 100 | fruit |
| Pear | B | 40 | fruit |
| Potato | F | 10 | fruit |
| Apple | E | 70 | None |

I get elements I also don't want, as I only want the elements from DF1 to be updated.

How can I only update rows in DF1 matching 'Asset Name' in DF2, and add the data from DF2 to those assets in DF1?

What I would like to achieve is the following:

| Asset Name | Score | Grade | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 70 | C | fruit |
| Pear | 60 | B | fruit |
| Banana | 100 | A | fruit |

Thanks

Comment: If `score` and `Grade` columns are all null in `df1` then u just need: `df1 = df1[['Asset Name', 'Type']].merge(df2, how='left', on=['Asset Name'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df = df2.set_index('Asset Name').combine_first(df1.set_index('Asset Name')).dropna().reset_index()
print (df)
  Asset Name Grade Score   Type
0      Apple     E    70  fruit
1     Banana     A   100  fruit
2       Pear     B    60  fruit
```

Comment: This doesn't quite provide what I need.
As you can see Apple, Pear and Banana are not updated as they should be.

Comment: @blupacetek - Can you check edited answer?

Comment: Thats what I was looking for, thanks Jezrael ! :-)